# Angular 9 Why a form group is displayed in the component but an error at the console saying that a form control of it is not defined?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I have a weird behavior of `FormGroup`.

What I am doing exactly is that I am generating `FormControls` into the desired form group, according to number of key properties of an array.

Lets say I have the following array:

```
arrayData = [
    {_id: 123, _name: 'XYZ', gender: 'Male'},
    {_id: 124, _name: 'XYW', gender: 'Female'}
];
```

The extracted arra properties are as the following:

```
this.odkDataIndexes = ['_id', 'name', 'gender'];
```

Now, for each index, I need to generate a form control into the `indexesForm` form group:

```
async createIndexesForm(extractedIndexesArray) {
  const controls = extractedIndexesArray.reduce((g, k) => {
    g[k] = '';
    return g;
  }, {});
  this.indexesForm = this.fb.group({controls});
  console.log(this.indexesForm);
}
```

This function will be fired, once the user click on a button having a click event: `(click)=generateMappingFields()`:

```
async generateMappingFields() {
    this.showFields = false;
    this.removeUnnecessaryFieldsMsg = '';
    if (this.odkDataIndexes.length > 0) {
      await this.createIndexesForm(this.odkDataIndexes).then(() => {
        this.showFields = true;
        this.tabIndex = 1;
      });
    }
}
```

For the `console.log(this.indexesForm);` output, the for appears to be created:

[image]

And it contains the following controls:

[image]

Which are exactly the same indexes, that I've extracted from my data.

Now I need to display these controls as following:

```
<div class="flexColEven">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="!indexesForm" value="50" class="setSpinnerOnTop" diameter="75" [color]="medair-color">
    </mat-spinner>
    <div *ngIf="showFields && indexesForm">
        <div [formGroup]="indexesForm" *ngIf="indexesForm" class="flexRow">
            <!-- {{indexesForm.valid | json}} -->
            <div *ngFor="let controlName of odkDataIndexes">
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <h3>ONA field: {{controlName}}</h3>
                </div>
                <mat-form-field class="formFieldWidth" color="warn" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>{{controlName}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-select [formControlName]="controlName">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let de of dataElementsDetails; let i = index;"
                            [value]="de.id">
                            {{de.displayName}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When `indexesForm` is created, I will show the div having a drop down list for each controller, which is showing properly, but showing at the same time an error, for each controller saying:

> core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '_id'
>
> core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '_tag'
>
> ...

But the fields are shown properly as this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asyykq) shows you.

And when I need to get the value of each drop down list:

```
mapping() {
  this.odkDataIndexes.forEach((arrayIndexControl) => {
    console.log(arrayIndexControl);
    console.log(this.indexesForm.get(arrayIndexControl));
  });
}
```

I can clearly see the `arrayIndexControl` which is the name of the form control of the `indexesForm` group, but the second console is displaying the following response:

> null

[image]

And if I consoled `(this.indexesForm.get(arrayIndexControl).value);`, it will return an error of undefined.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asyykq) having an example of data I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line `this.indexesForm = this.fb.group({controls});` you are creating a form group with a single form control in it called `controls`. Replace with this: `this.indexesForm = this.fb.group(controls);`

In general, doing `const obj = {controls};` is the same as `const obj = { controls: controls };`